# Changing width of heatmap in Seaborn to compensate for font size reduction

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a sentence like say

```
Hey I am feeling pretty boring today and the day is dull too
```

I pass it through the openai sentiment code which gives me some neuron weights which can be equal or little greater then number of words.

Neuron weights are

```
[ 0.01258736,  0.03544582,  0.08490616,  0.09010842,  0.07180552,
        0.07271874,  0.08906463,  0.09690772,  0.10281454,  0.08131664,
        0.08315734,  0.0790544 ,  0.07770097,  0.07302617,  0.07329235,
        0.06856266,  0.07642639,  0.08199468,  0.09079508,  0.09539193,
        0.09061056,  0.07109602,  0.02138061,  0.02364372,  0.00322057,
        0.01517018,  0.01150052,  0.00627739,  0.00445003,  0.00061127,
        0.0228037 , -0.29226044, -0.40493113, -0.4069235 , -0.39796737,
       -0.39871565, -0.39242673, -0.3537892 , -0.3779315 , -0.36448184,
       -0.36063945, -0.3506464 , -0.36719123, -0.37997353, -0.35103855,
       -0.34472692, -0.36256564, -0.35900915, -0.3619383 , -0.3532831 ,
       -0.35352525, -0.33328298, -0.32929575, -0.33149993, -0.32934144,
       -0.3261477 , -0.32421976, -0.3032671 , -0.47205922, -0.46902984,
       -0.45346943, -0.4518705 , -0.50997925, -0.50997925]
```

Now what I wanna do is plot a heatmap , the positive values shows positive sentiments while negative ones shows negative sentiment and I am plotting the heat map but the heatmap isn't plotting like it should be

[image: heatmap]

But when the sentence gets longer the whole sentence gets smaller and smaller that can't be seen ,So what changes should I do to make it show better.

Here is my plotting function:

```
def plot_neuron_heatmap(text, values, savename=None, negate=False, cell_height=.112, cell_width=.92):
    #n_limit = 832
    cell_height=.325
    cell_width=.15
    n_limit = count
    num_chars = len(text)
    text = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('\n', '\\n'), text))
    num_chars = len(text)
    total_chars = math.ceil(num_chars/float(n_limit))*n_limit
    mask = np.array([0]*num_chars + [1]*(total_chars-num_chars))
    text = np.array(text+[' ']*(total_chars-num_chars))
    values = np.array((values+[0])*(total_chars-num_chars))

    values = values.reshape(-1, n_limit)
    text = text.reshape(-1, n_limit)
    mask = mask.reshape(-1, n_limit)
    num_rows = len(values)
    plt.figure(figsize=(cell_width*n_limit, cell_height*num_rows))
    hmap=sns.heatmap(values, annot=text, mask=mask, fmt='', vmin=-5, vmax=5, cmap='RdYlGn',xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, cbar=False)
    plt.subplots_adjust() 
    #plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('fig1.png')
    #plt.show()
```

This is how it shows the lengthy text as

[image: for lengthy text]

What I want it to show

[image]

Here is a link to the full notebook: https://github.com/yashkumaratri/testrepo/blob/master/heatmap.ipynb

Mad Physicist , Your code does this
[image]
and what really it should do is
[image]

Comment: If it's only 12 lines, post it here. Don't expect people to go offsite to help you.

Comment: Show an example of a longer sentence, and show what you want it to look like instead. The example here seems totally fine and it's hard to get a picture of what you want with the information provided. For example, do you want to insert newlines? Do you want to be able to scroll through a longer sentence?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8I57H this is what it does

Comment: I ran the model on @MadPhysicist comment and the font got too small, Is doesn't even break the line.

Comment: Can you post that into your question? It seems like fairly crucial information. Don't forget to add a clear description of what exactly you want it to do instead. I gave you a couple of options. It seems like you want to insert line breaks?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Updated the question , Can you help me with this tricky issue.

Comment: I believe I can. Thanks for being responsive.

Comment: Please do not share personal information on SO.

Comment: This site is a Q&A for everyone to benefit, not just you. If you are away for too long or have lost interest in this problem, that is fine.

Comment: Can you provide me with (A) the long text, so I can run my tests, (B), the `values` argument for the long text? I am assuming that the weights you show in the question are the `values` argument for the short text.

Comment: "equal or little greater then number of words" should be "equal or little greater then number of **characters**"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shrinkage of the font you are seeing is to be expected. As you add more characters horizontally, the font shrinks to fit everything in. There are a couple of solutions for this. The simplest would be to break your text into smaller chunks, and display them as you show in your desired output. Also, you can print your figure with a different DPI with what is shown on the screen, so that the letters will look fine in the image file.

You should consider cleaning up your function along the way:

1. `count` appears to be a global that is never used.
2. You redefine variables without ever using the original value (e.g. `num_chars` and the input parameters).
3. You have a whole bunch of variables you don't really use.
4. You recompute a lot of quantities multiple times.
5. The expression `list(map(lambda x: x.replace('\n', '\\n'), text))` is total overkill: `list(text.replace('\n', '\\n'))` does the same thing.
6. Given that `len(values) != len(text)` for most cases, the line `values = np.array((values+[0])*(total_chars-num_chars))` is nonsense and needs cleanup.
7. You are constructing numpy arrays by doing padding operations on lists, instead of using the power of numpy.
8. You have the entire infrastructure for properly reshaping your arrays already in place, but you don't use it.

The updated version below fixes the minor issues and adds `n_limit` as a parameter, which determines how many characters you are willing to have in a row of the heat map. As I mentioned in the last item, you already have all the necessary code to reshape your arrays properly, and even mask out the extra tail you end up with sometimes. The only thing that is wrong is the `-1` in the shape, which always resolves to one row because of the remainder of the shape. Additionally, the figure is always saved at 100dpi, so the results should come out consistent for a given width, no matter how many rows you end up with. The DPI affects PNG because it increases or decreases the total number of pixels in the image, and PNG does not actually understand DPI:

```
def plot_neuron_heatmap(text, values, n_limit=80, savename='fig1.png',
                        cell_height=0.325, cell_width=0.15, dpi=100):
    text = text.replace('\n', '\\n')
    text = np.array(list(text + ' ' * (-len(text) % n_limit)))
    if len(values) > text.size:
        values = np.array(values[:text.size])
    else:
        t = values
        values = np.zeros(text.shape, dtype=np.int)
        values[:len(t)] = t
    text = text.reshape(-1, n_limit)
    values = values.reshape(-1, n_limit)
    # mask = np.zeros(values.shape, dtype=np.bool)
    # mask.ravel()[values.size:] = True
    plt.figure(figsize=(cell_width * n_limit, cell_height * len(text)))
    hmap = sns.heatmap(values, annot=text, fmt='', vmin=-5, vmax=5, cmap='RdYlGn', xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, cbar=False)
    plt.subplots_adjust()
    plt.savefig(savename if savename else 'fig1.png', dpi=dpi)
```

Here are a couple of sample runs of the function:

```
text = 'Hey I am feeling pretty boring today and the day is dull too'
values = [...] # The stuff in your question

plot_neuron_heatmap(text, values)
plot_neuron_heatmap(text, values, 20)
plot_neuron_heatmap(text, values, 7)
```

results in the following three figures:

[image: n_limit=80]

[image: n_limit=20]

[image: n_limit=7]

Comment: By the way, the little padding optimization of `-len(text) % n_limit` is courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/49903694/2988730

Comment: I have updated the long text in my notebook https://github.com/yashkumaratri/testrepo/blob/master/heatmap.ipynb

Comment: There are large number of neuron values so I am not pasting them here.

Comment: @RyanAdlob. Fair enough. Given my code, I don't think there is a need.

Comment: There is some trouble with your code, It is only coloring the text as yellow , no green shading or yellow shading.

Comment: I have updated the question with what my code does and what your code is doing.

Comment: @RyanAdlob. Please ask a separate question if you have a separate issue. SO is not a personal helpdesk.

Comment: In the meantime, try reinstating the mask, which I temporarily removed.