# Simple way to calculate padding based on modulo/remainder

Tags: python, padding, modulo

If I have a string of length L=77 that I want to pad to a length that is a multiple of N=10. I am interested in computing just the amount of padding required. This can be easily done with `N - (L % N)`, except for cases where `L % N` is zero.

I have been using the following for now:

```
pad = (N - (L % N)) % N
```

This does not seem particularly legible, so sometimes I use

```
pad = N - (L % N)
if pad == N:
    pad = 0
```

It seems overkill to use three lines of code for something so simple.

Alternatively, I can find the `k` for which `k * N >= L`, but using `math.ceil` seems like overkill as well.

Is there a better alternative that I am missing? Perhaps a simple function somewhere?

Comment: Isn't it enough to use `N - L`?

Comment: @MegaIng. Sorry, was unclear. Updated the question.

Comment: Why don't use string formatting options for this?

Comment: @alec_djinn. Because the fact that we are talking about strings is irrelevant. For that matter, what string formatting options?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for the clarification. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309255/how-to-pad-a-string-to-a-fixed-length-with-spaces-in-python for padding solutions using string formatting

Comment: Is this being computed in a very hot loop or something? You seem rather worried about an extra subtraction or a call to math.ceil

Comment: @GrantWilliams. Purely a matter of aesthetics. Functionally, I am perfectly happy with my double modulus. Or `ceil`, or really even the `if` statement.

Comment: @alec_djinn. All the options the answers suggest imply a prior knowledge of the total width. I am trying to avoid computing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The modulus of negative L will do it.

```
pad = -L % N
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this one enough?

```
pad = (N - L) % N
```

Comment: That actually reduces to the accepted answer. Clever.

Answer (score 1):

With `math.ceil`:

```
from math import ceil

def pad(l, n):
    return n*ceil(l/n) - l

assert pad(59, 10) == 1
assert pad(60, 10) == 0
assert pad(61, 10) == 9
```

Comment: That does not seem any simpler than taking the modulo twice, but may be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I mean couldn't you simply do

```
pad = N-L if N-L > 0 else 0
```

Comment: Sorry, but my question was unclear. I updated it. I wanted to find the padding for cases where the final length needs to be some arbitrary multiple of `N`, where I don't know the multiple. Unfortunately, I've basically invalidated your answer. My apologies.

Comment: Also, I object to computing the difference twice for cases where it is nonzero, which reduces this solution to using the `if` statement that makes me unhappy.

Comment: fair enough. You could have also used `pad = max(N-L, 0)` if you wanted. Although i cant imagine an extra subtraction is going to matter all that much

Answer (score 0):

Use the [tenary conditional operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator):

```
0 if (L % N) == 0 else N - (L % N)
```